# Expresso Store: Is login required to place orders?

Tags: expresso-store

To place orders or to add the items to the cart,is login required ?

EE version: 2.6.1
Store modules version: 2.0.3

Comment: Just a friendly reminder to mark answers as correct if they solve your question :)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can allow users can [checkout as guests](https://exp-resso.com/docs/settings_general.html#require_member_account_to_place_orders).

See **Require Member Account to Place Orders** in the above link.

EDIT: added heading to clarify the intended reference.